Can't issue a certificate through the cer-manager in Kubernetes
can anyone tell me? I installed a cluster on two purchased VMs, one is a master node, the other is for workers. I installed Metallb in the cluster, then installed Ingress Controller Nginx, checked, everything works. I can create ingresses and resolve them across locations. It was the turn of cert-manager, it installed everything fine, created a ClusterIssuer, corrected ingress, but the certificate was not issued. I started skimming along the route, got to the challenge and there was this message:
Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: wrong status code '404', expected '200'

From the outside there is access to the URL in which the secret is, but for some reason cert-manager apparently cannot get to the URL and writes 404. I installed it under a multitool and started checking the domain using Curl, and as it turned out from under it, it leads to an unknown external IP, I registered an entry in coredns, checked using dig, the domain resolves correctly via dig, but via curl and ping the IP address is again incorrect.
Has anyone encountered this?
diplom-app-deployment-7ccd7f4d99-2kvcn:/# dig wehealthy.ru

; <<>> DiG 9.18.16 <<>> wehealthy.ru
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27560
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: d5bb4fd7d14556f1 (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wehealthy.ru.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wehealthy.ru.           30      IN      A       82.146.35.54

;; Query time: 140 msec
;; SERVER: 169.254.25.10#53(169.254.25.10) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 24 06:55:36 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 81

diplom-app-deployment-7ccd7f4d99-2kvcn:/# ping wehealthy.ru
PING wehealthy.ru.DOMAINS (75.126.102.234) 56(84) bytes of data.


In the ingress controller and ser-manager pods the following logs:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/177GaFe8fLIPma2DX5qTaYnrGv15r6YPGT-9QP05Wcko/edit?usp=sharing

ClusterIssuer manifest
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: adminzztop245@gmail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          ingressClassName: nginx

I tried to register an entry in Corednes but it did not help.
        hosts {
            82.146.35.54 wehealthy.ru
            fallthrough
        }

It is often advised to check the ingress class and if there is a public one, register it, but I don’t have it.
kubectl get ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io -A
NAME    CONTROLLER             PARAMETERS   AGE
nginx   k8s.io/ingress-nginx   <none>       2d6h


The problem was that the kubilet inherited the dns settings from the /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf node, which is where I had a DOMAINS record, which was added to the URL of any path if you look at it from the kubernets pod (wehealthy.ru.DOMAINS). It turns out that my domain did not resolve from the pod, and if the domain does not resolve from the cert manager, then you will not pass the HTTP1 domain check and the certificate will not be issued.
You can remove DOMAINS on the node in the file /etc/network/if-up.d/resolved in line 41:
DOMAINS=DOMAINS
needs to be reduced to:
DOMAINS=
if global parameters will be used. After changing the server, the server needs to be rebooted.
